# Can not find index form observablearray knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to find index from an observableArray (Mainly I will grab the Product price from here).

I am using for that ***indexOf***

but it's always return ***-1***

My view Model is.

```
var myviewmodel = function(){
var self = this;
    self.SetId = ko.observable();
    self.ProductId=ko.observable();
    self.Productname=ko.observable();
    self.Products = ko.observableArray([{"ProductId":"5dca48ae-5378-4c2b-a8ea-17702b722d4f","Productname":"Prd1","Price":12.00},{"ProductId":"8b91a6e6-e9b4-4dc4-b32d-2fdba61cb707","Productname":"Prd2","Price":777.00}]);

     self.changeProp = function (text) {
        var AllProducts = text.Products();
              console.log(ko.toJSON(AllProducts));
              console.log(self.SetId());
         //var thisindex = text.Products().indexOf(self.SetId());
var thisindex = AllProducts.indexOf(self.SetId());//text.Products().length;
         console.log(thisindex);  

         //var Price = text.Products()[thisindex].Price;
           //  console.log("Price: "+ Price);

           }
}
ko.applyBindings(new myviewmodel());
```

I am using knockout.js version 2.1.0

Any one please tell me the solution. I have made a copy of the code [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Ronjon/efaDL/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `optionsValue: 'ProductId'` setting you tell KO to use your `ProductId` values to store in the `SetId` property.

However in your `AllProducts` you still store the whole product objects so of course `AllProducts.indexOf(self.SetId());` will return -1 because it doesn't know to which property it should compare your `SetId`.

One solution is to create a new array with `ko.utils.arrayMap` from `AllProducts` which contains the ids and use the `indexOf` on that:

```
var thisindex = ko.utils.arrayMap(AllProducts, function(item){ 
    return item.ProductId; }).indexOf(self.SetId());
console.log(thisindex);
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qt78D/).

Or you can tell to KO to set your whole Product object in the `SetId` property (in this case you should probably rename the property) with removing the `optionsValue: 'ProductId'` setting, in this case you don't need the `indexOf` call at all, and you can just write:

```
console.log("Price: "+ self.SetId().Price);
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kK8Jg/).

Or if you anyway just need the price you can use `optionsValue: 'Price'` in this case the `SetId` property will be store the selected price directly.